# Notepad++ Removing text between two strings if third string is present between other strings

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I would like to remove the text between two strings, including those strings, if and only if a third string is present between those two strings. I would greatly prefer it if I could use the replace functionality in Notepad++ to do this.

Here's a mock-up of what I need altered:

```
asdfnjaslfjsa
asdfjaskldfsafkldj
asdfjsadfk
STRING_1
sanjvnlamf
 fas g
gsegvrs 
STRING_2
STRING_1
asf sf gfsjasak
qweuwiouqnv
STRING_3
awi iavbfa c
anfiab
STRING_2
STRING_1
asmorancm
anib fas
STRING_2
sdabfashbdfbc  ds
```

Changed to this:

```
asdfnjaslfjsa
asdfjaskldfsafkldj
asdfjsadfk
STRING_1
sanjvnlamf
 fas g
gsegvrs 
STRING_2
STRING_1
asmorancm
anib fas
STRING_2
sdabfashbdfbc  ds
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you, mark it as solution please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for can be achieved with the following construct:

```
STRING_1
(?:(?!STRING_2)[\s\S])*?
STRING_3
(?:(?!STRING_2)[\s\S])*?
STRING_2
```

This matches `STRING_1` to `STRING_2` only if `STRING_3` is present in between (the technique is called a **tempered greedy token**).

---

You can put it in one line as well:

```
STRING_1(?:(?!STRING_2)[\s\S])*?STRING_3(?:(?!STRING_2)[\s\S])*?STRING_2
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hU6tY6/2).

Comment: Beautiful! I was working on it, but couldn't get around a problem where the regex matched the _first_ STRING_1 up to the correct STRING_2

Comment: @Shovalt: If you want some literature: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Comment: Thanks! I had spent a lot of time trying to figure it out myself before I came here. In the end though, I threw this together: `STRING_1(\n.*){2,7}STRING_3(\n.*){5,50}?STRING_2` - because STRING_3 was always just a few lines away from STRING_1 when it was present, and STRING_2 was always further away, so if `STRING_1(\n.*){2,7}STRING_3` found something, it was always the last STRING_1 before the STRING_3. Not as elegant as your solution, and certainly not as versatile. I used `(\n.*){5,50}?STRING_2` simply because I couldn't get `(\n.*)*?STRING_2` to work there; Do you know why?